# Задача поиска в appDesigner MATLAB

Tags: gui, matlab, app

Есть глобальная таблица p.data, которая заполняется так же в интерфейсе, при нажатии кнопки. Задачу поиска я попробовал реализовать таким образом в функции Button_2:

```
     % Button pushed function: Button_2

     function Button_2Pushed(app, event)
     global p
     global u
     a = app.edit6.Value;    
     u.data = strcmp(a, p.data);
     disp(u.data);
```

Но на выходе я получил матрицу:

0   0   0   0   0

0   0   0   0   0

0   0   0   0   0

0   0   0   0   0

1   0   0   0   0

0   0   0   0   0

-где вместо внесённых данных были "0" и "1", при чём 1 - это слово, которое я искал.

Как сделать так, что бы Button_2 выводила данные вместо цифр, при чём всего одну строку?

Answer (score 0):

```
    % Button pushed function: Button_2
    function Button_2Pushed(app, event)
     global p
     global u

     a = app.edit6.Value;

        u.data = strcmp(a, p.data);
        [I, ~] = find(u.data);
        disp(p.data(I,:));
    end
end
```

Спасибо, не надо, я всё сделал :)